# How to output raw HTML in CakePHP 2.2?

Tags: html, cakephp

I have this property which is HTML saved from a TinyMCE editor:

```
<?php echo h($person['Person']['CurriculumVitae']); ?>
```

How can I have it displayed on the web and rendered as RAW Html not a simple string?

Comment: Please don't delete your questions unless it's a completely unworthy question.  I spent 5 minutes writing a verbose answer to your question about Persona model associations only to have it say "This question has been deleted by it's author".  Leave the question, and feel free to answer it yourself, but don't delete it.  It can help future people too, not just you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't wrap the variable in `h()`, an alias for `htmlspecialchars()`, which escapes HTML entities:

```
<?php echo $person['Person']['CurriculumVitae']; ?>
```

Comment: That's not a good idea either because you can now inject malicious code through this field if there is no sanitazion happening at all.

Comment: I don't disagree, but the OP did ask for *raw* — nothing quite as raw as getting XSSed! ;-) In my opinion, the sanitization should happen on the way in (when handling the submission), not the way out.

Answer (score 2):

Just to remove the h() might solve your issue but it will open possible security holes because the field that keeps the html from TinyMCE will now become a possible security hole.

I had the exact same issue and solved it by using http://htmlpurifier.org/ for the output of tinymce HTML. I've written also a CakePHP plugin around it. https://github.com/burzum/HtmlPurifier

HtmlPurifier will allow you to configure an allowed set of Html elements and even of it's attributes. So you could for example specify that href is allowed but class is not.

You'll need to create a config for HtmlPurifier that will match whatever you allow your users to do with TinyMce. It will remove all non allowed tags and attributes from the markup the user has entered.